# Format and convert JSON to GeoJSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geojson, json

I'd like to convert this JSON file to GeoJSON using JavaScript and use it with leaflet.js, it's a LineString file, I'm trying it using geojson.js but without success.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.2.3/dist/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/GeoJSON.js-master/GeoJSON.js-master/geojson.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>


    var map = L.map('map').setView([23.5795, 46.5110], 7);
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Topographic').addTo(map);

    var sample =
      [{
        "track":
          [
            {
              "start": "14/02/2020-08:40", "end": "14/02/2020-12:55", "coordinates":
                [{ "latitude": "23.5795193", "longitude": "46.5110261", "time": "14/02/2020-08:43" },
                { "latitude": "23.6795193", "longitude": "46.5110263", "time": "14/02/2020-08:45" },
                { "latitude": "23.7795193", "longitude": "46.5110264", "time": "14/02/2020-08:50" },
                { "latitude": "23.8795193", "longitude": "46.5110265", "time": "14/02/2020-08:58" },
                { "latitude": "23.9795193", "longitude": "46.5110266", "time": "14/02/2020-08:59" },
                { "latitude": "23.5795193", "longitude": "46.5110261", "time": "14/02/2020-09:43" },
                { "latitude": "23.6795193", "longitude": "46.5110263", "time": "14/02/2020-10:45" },
                { "latitude": "23.7795193", "longitude": "46.5110264", "time": "14/02/2020-11:50" },
                { "latitude": "23.8795193", "longitude": "46.5110265", "time": "14/02/2020-11:58" },
                { "latitude": "23.9795193", "longitude": "46.5110266", "time": "14/02/2020-12:55" }]
            },

            {
              "start": "14/02/2020-08:40", "coordinates":
                [{ "latitude": "29.5795123", "longitude": "46.5110261", "time": "14/02/2020-13:43" },
                { "latitude": "29.6795133", "longitude": "46.5110263", "time": "14/02/2020-13:45" },
                { "latitude": "29.7795153", "longitude": "46.5110264", "time": "14/02/2020-13:50" },
                { "latitude": "29.8795163", "longitude": "46.5110265", "time": "14/02/2020-13:58" },
                { "latitude": "29.9795173", "longitude": "46.5110266", "time": "14/02/2020-14:59" },
                { "latitude": "29.5795183", "longitude": "46.5110261", "time": "14/02/2020-15:43" },
                { "latitude": "29.6795193", "longitude": "46.5110263", "time": "14/02/2020-16:45" }]
            }
          ]
      }]

    var result = GeoJSON.parse(sample, { MultiLineString: 'coordinates' });
    var geojson = L.geoJson().addData(result);
    geojson.addTo(map)


  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

It return a geometry undefined, I believe that problem is that the JSON doesn't have a colunm lat and long, my JSON file has the colunm coordinates with 3 atributes string.

Comment: Please include the code you have already written, this will make it easier to offer advice.

Comment: thanks for answer,I put all the code.

Comment: Just from your code. I saw something which is incorrect. The first one is, maybe you meant to use JSON.parse () which take string of object as a parameter not GeoJSON. Parse (something). And the second one is var sample is not a valid GeoJSON string